# Why is it that transitive seeming expressions like 蜘蛛の子を散らす and 波を打つ act intransitive

Tags: transitivity

I can partly understand 波を打つ but the only thing I don't understand is how hitting the waves would cause undulation or resemble it, but I don't understand how 蜘蛛の子を散らす is intransitive. You're not the spiders being scattered, you're the scatterer. So why does it mean to scatter in all directions like baby spiders? You don't scatter to scatter baby spiders...

Comment: Both 散らす and 打つ are transitive verbs. 散る is intransitive verb. Can you better explain what you do not understand?

Comment: Do you ever do your research before answering my questions or are they just THAT confusing? Sorry for sounding condescending even though I am in such a mood. https://jisho.org/search/namiutu https://jisho.org/search/kumonokowotirasu

Comment: I am still confused about what you are thinking exactly. Have you seen these expressions in some text? Are you expecting different particles or something there? Are you trying to write some text with these expressions?

Comment: These are idiomatic expressions. You shouldn't expect the transitivity of their construction to relate to the English grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 散らす and 打つ are transitive. So, theoretically, once they have an object such as 波 or 蜘蛛の子, they no longer take an additional one: they are now intransitive.

波を打つ can be seen as an example of 結果の目的語. It is a phenomenon that the direct object (marked with the particle を) is not actually a recipient of the action but a result of it. The most famous example is that "to boil water" is rarely expressed as 水を沸かす but almost always as 湯を沸かす. (This kind of direct object can be seen also in English. e.g. "dig a hole" used to mean "dig ground and/to make a hole") So here, 波を打つ means the subject (ocean, lake etc.) beats something and it results in waves.

蜘蛛の子を散らす is almost always followed by the auxiliary verb "よう(だ)" and depict the state of people going/getting/running away in all direction. One never say

> 彼らは蜘蛛の子を散らした。

as an idiomatic sense, but say

> 彼らは蜘蛛の子を散らしたように逃げた。

Comment: This was a good answer. I should have said "why is x not a expression that takes に"